# Verify symmetric difference identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anybody help me with the following problem?

**Let $A,B,C\subset X$. The symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$ is $A\triangle B:=(A\backslash B)\cup (B\backslash A)$. Verify that $$(A\cup B\cup C)\backslash (A\cap B\cap C)=(A\triangle B)\cup (B\triangle C).$$**

The statement makes perfect sense, but I am unsure of how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding the expression on the right hand side, and rearranging and regrouping the terms using the commutativity and associativity of union:
\begin{align*}
(A \triangle B) \cup (B \triangle C) & =
[(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)] \cup [(B \setminus C) \cup (C \setminus B)] \\ & = [(A \setminus B) \cup (C \setminus B)] \cup [(B \setminus A) \cup (B \setminus C)] \\ & = [(A \cup C) \setminus B] \cup [B \setminus (A \cap C)].
\end{align*}
Knowing what to aim for, one can transform the expression on the left hand side:
\begin{align*}
(A \cup B \cup C) \setminus (A \cap B \cap C) & =
[(A \cup C) \cup B)] \setminus (A \cap B \cap C) \\ & =
[((A \cup C) \setminus B) \cup B] \setminus (A \cap B \cap C) \\ & =
[((A \cup C) \setminus B) \setminus (A \cap B \cap C)] \cup [B \setminus (A \cap B \cap C)].
\end{align*}
It is now painless to prove that
\begin{gather*}
((A \cup C) \setminus B) \setminus (A \cap B \cap C) = (A \cup C) \setminus B, \\
B \setminus (A \cap B \cap C) = B \setminus (A \cap C),
\end{gather*}
showing that the two sides are equal.

(Intuitively, the left hand side denotes the set of elements of $X$ belonging to one or two of the subsets $A$, $B$, and $C$, but not all three.  The right hand side denotes the same set expressed asymmetrically in respect of $B$.  One could even give a proof along these lines using [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), but I found it less fussy to use known set-theoretic identities to rearrange the right hand side to express the asymmetric role of $B$ more clearly, then brute-force the left hand side into line. It's a matter of taste. Mine may be questionable!)

Answer (score 0):

By [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),
\begin{align*}(A\cup B\cup C)\backslash (A\cap B\cap C)&=
(A\cup B\cup C)\cap(A\cap B\cap C)^c
=
(A\cup B\cup C)\cap(A^c\cup B^c\cup C^c)\\
&=(A\cap B^c)\cup (A\cap C^c)\cup (B\cap A^c)\cup (B\cap C^c)
\cup (C\cap A^c)\cup (C\cap B^c)\\
&=(A\triangle B)\cup(B\triangle C)\cup(A\triangle C).
\end{align*}
Hence the equality holds as soon as we show that
$$(A\triangle B)\cup(B\triangle C)\supseteq (A\triangle C),$$
that is
$$(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c)\cup
(C\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap C^c)\supseteq (A\cap C^c)\cup (C\cap A^c)$$
which is true because
$$(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap C^c)\supseteq 
((A\cap C^c)\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap (A\cap C^c))=(A\cap C^c)$$
and, similarly,
$$(C\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c)\supseteq 
((C\cap A^c)\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap (C\cap A^c))=(C\cap A^c).$$

Comment: @user405381 Any further doubt?